# Android: Cannot find wanted API level in SDK

Tags: android, sdk

Good evening!

I am having troubles with my SDK. I want to install the ARM EABI found in API14 (Android 4.0), however, when I try to go to Android SDK manager, it only loads up to 15, but skips API14 entirely. How do I remedy this?

[image]

Comment: See `Tools -> Options` and `Clear cache`. Then try to refresh the content

Comment: Are you sure that you have not installed earlier??

Comment: How about updating the SDK Tools itself to the newest Version first?

Comment: @Thommy how do I update SDK tools?

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com there is no Clear Cache option under tools

Comment: Toosl -> Options. Clear Cache is a button there (at least in SDK manager here). See About. Mine is rev 21rc3

Comment: Updated my post. Not there @WebnetMobile.com

Comment: Maybe you got something so ancient that it fails to update itself? Fetch recent SDK manager and at least try to unpack it to other directory to see if it would work better. if so, then either update your copy in old location or do the fresh setup (mind AVD settings are there, so you may need to copy it)

Comment: Just Click "Install 1 package" as shown in your screenshot. The SDK Package Update is already marked for install

Answer (score 1):

in the screenshot it didnt even finish loading and only shows the ones installed.

Be sure the URLS under Tools --> Manage Add-on Sites are all enabled and let it fetch everything. The current URL for Android System Images is

`https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img.xml`

Else you may have a problem with connecting to google servers.

Your SDK tools arent the newest anyway, so you may want to update them too and check if you still cant get any information from the google servers.

Comment: can you open the URL in your web browser?

Comment: if yes, your SDK has problems connecting to the URL and you should update/reinstall it. if no, your internet connection has problems connecting to google servers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, On your Android SDK Manager **menus**:

- Packages >> Show updates/New packages; Show Obsolete packages;
- Tools >> Manage Add-on sites: ==> tick all the sources (especially Google)

Answer (score 0):

What's in your /platform-tools/source.properties ???

```
Pkg.Revision=14
Archive.Arch=ANY
Pkg.SourceUrl=https\://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-7.xml
```

Comment: ### Android Tool: Source of this archive.
#Sat Jun 30 01:26:48 CST 2012
Archive.Os=WINDOWS
Pkg.Revision=12
Archive.Arch=ANY
Pkg.SourceUrl=https\://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-6.xml